# Replace quotation marks with \"

Tags: javascript, string, replace, quotation-marks

I am working with a html-page with some javascript on it. What I'm trying to do is to show a message and a button after pressing submit-button. On pressing this new button the document state should go to its previous state. My attempt:

```
function Submin()
{
  var str=document.Inputs.innerHTML;
  newstr = str.replace("\"", "\\\"");
  document.Inputs.innerHTML="<p style=\"text-align:center\">The data has been successfully submitted <br /><input type=\"button\" value=\"Back\" onclick=\"document.Inputs.innerHTML=\\\"" + newstr + "\\\" \/></p>";
}
```

I am totally confused by escaping and double escaping things. But in my opinion it should work somehow like this. Can sombody help me on this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use single quotes inside your double quoted string.  Second, don't use inline event handlers here.  Your best bet is to use a real event handler:

```
function Submin() {
    var str=document.Inputs.innerHTML;
    document.Inputs.innerHTML="<p style='text-align:center'>The data has been successfully submitted <br /><input type='button' value='Back' ></p>";
    document.Inputs.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onclick = function() {
        document.Inputs.innerHTML = newstr;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you were a great help!